# adding Woocommerce attribute to a product via API

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

Ok, so, I have a fair bit of experience with the Woocommerce API and PHP and use it for lots of product population from XML files. However, I'm having a problem adding attributes. Well, thats not strictly true, the attributes DO add, but then throw up an error after they do.

I'm using the Automattic PHP code and, as I say, it does most things fine.

```
$data = [
'attributes' => [
      [
        'id' => 9, 
        'position' => 0,
        'visible' => true,
        'variation' => false,
        'options' => [
          'bathroom'
         ]
      ]
  ]
];

$woocommerce->put('products/123', $data);
```

but that gives me the error

'Error: Invalid parameter(s): attributes [rest_invalid_param]' in 
 /vendor/automattic/woocommerce/src/WooCommerce/HttpClient/HttpClient.php:348 Stack trace: #0

Although when I look at the product, the attribute has been added correctly.

Comment: Do you remember how have you solved it?